# How to read MQ base queue name using wsadmin script?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I want to read bas queue names inside the queues, have written code but which only able to read the last queue name instead of all.

Below is a code

```
queueList = AdminConfig.list('MQQueue', AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + AdminControl.getCell() + '/')).splitlines()


for queue in queueList:

           print "\t" + queue +"in QueueList"

queueName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(queue, 'baseQueueName')

print queueName
```

The queue is reading only the last queue name from queueList, I want it to read all the base queue names present inside queues.

Comment: Don't you need to indent  the last 2 lines to make them part of the for loop? Right now it will print the `in QueueList` message for each queue but only the `QueueName` on the last queue.

Comment: I formalized the information into an answer.  Please let me know if you have any further questions or need any clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help, I tried as earlier you mentioned and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script as currently written will only execute the following line for each queue in the `queueList`:

```
print "\t" + queue +"in QueueList"
```

You need to indent the last 2 lines to make them part of the for loop, otherwise they are only executed once after the loop is finished, at that point `queue` will have the value of the last queue.

```
queueList = AdminConfig.list('MQQueue', AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + AdminControl.getCell() + '/')).splitlines()


for queue in queueList:

           print "\t" + queue +"in QueueList"

           queueName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(queue, 'baseQueueName')

           print queueName
```